# How to change size of column in Yahoo Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

I tried to change the size of column when I view my mail, because the name of the sender too small. In Setting there is no option to change this while viewing email.

Is it possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, any webpage can be customized by using **GreaseMonkey** plugin. However, it will require you to know some basic javascript programming.